# Merging list of list into a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, merge

I am trying to merge a list of list which consists of Date index as every list into a single dataframe on axis=1.
Please find the code below:

```
d=[]
for i in range(0,Alpha.shape[0]-1):
    d.append(pd.date_range(start=Alpha.iloc[i]['Month_year'], end=Alpha.iloc[i+1]['Month_year']-pd.DateOffset(days=1), freq='D'))
```

The Above code creates a series of date index as below:

```
[DatetimeIndex(['2014-04-01', '2014-04-02', '2014-04-03', '2014-04-04',
            '2014-04-05', '2014-04-06', '2014-04-07', '2014-04-08',
            '2014-04-09', '2014-04-10', '2014-04-11', '2014-04-12',
            '2014-04-13', '2014-04-14', '2014-04-15', '2014-04-16',
            '2014-04-17', '2014-04-18', '2014-04-19', '2014-04-20',
            '2014-04-21', '2014-04-22', '2014-04-23', '2014-04-24',
            '2014-04-25', '2014-04-26', '2014-04-27', '2014-04-28',
            '2014-04-29', '2014-04-30'],
           dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D'),
DatetimeIndex(['2014-05-01', '2014-05-02', '2014-05-03', '2014-05-04',
            '2014-05-05', '2014-05-06', '2014-05-07', '2014-05-08',
            '2014-05-09', '2014-05-10', '2014-05-11', '2014-05-12',
            '2014-05-13', '2014-05-14', '2014-05-15', '2014-05-16',
            '2014-05-17', '2014-05-18', '2014-05-19', '2014-05-20',
            '2014-05-21', '2014-05-22', '2014-05-23', '2014-05-24',
            '2014-05-25', '2014-05-26', '2014-05-27', '2014-05-28',
            '2014-05-29', '2014-05-30', '2014-05-31'],....
```

What I wanted is to merge the list 'd' into a dataframe. When I tried the below,

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(d)):
    for j in range(0,len(d[i])):
        df.append(d[i][j])
```

I am getting the following error,

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

Could you please help me in resolving this issue?
I want all the date in the column wise manner.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you add sample data of DataFrame?

Comment: yes @jezrael I can add sample data to the dataframe  df.append([1,2,3])

Comment: thank you, also need new DataFrame by values from `merged list`s? Or columns?

Comment: a new dataframe say df.. I want the date value to be in the column. Say the first index of the new dataframe df is '2014-04-01', and index 2 is '2014-04-02' and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.concatenate(d))
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your quick replies. I also got the same result using the below code :  for i in range(0,len(d)):
    for j in range(0,len(d[i])):
        df=df.append([d[i][j]])             Just added square brackets around